# NASM assembled bootloader memory issue

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

I am writing a bootloader with nasm. At the moment it is designed to output a welcome string, then record keystrokes while displaying them, printing the stored keystrokes upon finding the enter key, and finally halting.

```
                bits       16
                org        0x7C00
start:          jmp        main

bgetkey:        pusha
                mov        ax, 0
                mov        ah, 10h
                int        16h
                mov        [.buf], ax
                popa
                mov        ax, [.buf]
                ret
                .buf       dw 0

prints:         mov        ah, 0x0e
                mov        al, [si]
                cmp        al, 0
                jz         print_end
                mov        bh, 0x00
                mov        bl, 0x07
                int        0x10
                inc        si
                jmp        prints
print_end:      ret

main:           mov        ax, 0x0000           ; set register a
                mov        ds, ax               ; 
                mov        bx, mem
                add        bx, word 1
                mov        word [mem], bx
                mov        si, welcome          ; set and prints
                call       prints               ; 
type:           mov        si, qbuf             ; set prints ptr
                call       bgetkey              ; capture  input
                mov        [qbuf], al           ; set char to sz
                call       prints               ; call print str

                mov        bx, [mem]            ; put chr in mem
                cmp        bx, stop             ; compare loader
                je         oom                  ; end and memory
                mov        byte [bx], al
                add        bx, byte 1
                mov        [mem], bx            ; 

                cmp        byte [qbuf], 0x0D    ; cmpr enter key
                jne        type                 ; continue  next
                mov        si, newline          ; print  newline
                call       prints               ; 

                mov        bx, mem
printmem:       cmp        byte [bx], 0x00      ; check for zero
                je         halt                 ; halt  the  cpu
                mov        cl, [bx]
                mov        byte [qbuf], cl      ; buffer and cpy
                mov        si, qbuf             ; pointer to  si
                call       prints               ; print the char
                inc        bx
                jmp        printmem             ; jump beginning

oom:            mov        si, outomem          ; no more memory
                call       prints               ; print  message

halt:           mov        si, halting          ; cpu is halting
                call       prints               ; print last msg
                hlt                             ; halt  the  cpu

                welcome db "bootloader", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                newline db 0x0A, 0x00
                outomem db "out of memory", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                halting db "halting", 0x00
                qbuf       dw 0, 0
                mem        db 0

times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)db 0
                stop       dw 0xAA55
```

The program is not functioning as desired. It ceaselessly prints the same character after enter is pressed. How is this error corrected?

Comment: `mov [mem], cx` looks "funny" to me. Do you intend `bx` there?

Comment: You forget to specify a stack segment and a stack pointer.

Comment: @FrankKotler yes, I meant to put `bx`

Comment: The differences in the two memory dumps are expected. Your code modifies the memory locations `.buf` and `qbuf`. They contain the ASCII code for a carriage return, presumably because you pressed the return key. You example program doesn't define `mem` so doesn't assemble. Your program uses `mem` inconsistently. Sometimes it treats it as an address of a buffer, and sometimes it treats it as an address where an address of a buffer is stored.

Comment: @RossRidge The idea is `[mem]` points to memory starting at `[mem + 2]`

Comment: I spent some time re-formatting the current assembly file for the web. It should compile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your `prints` destroys `bx` (because it sets `bl` and `bh`) so your `printmem` loop which requires `bx` to be preserved blows up.

However, it also destroys `al` so your input loop won't be storing the correct value in memory to start with, either.

Furthermore, while you want `mem` to be a pointer to `mem + 2`, it is actually a pointer to `mem + 1` so you overwrite the pointer with the input. Also, you start printing from `mem` and not `mem + 2`.

Finally, your input is not terminated by a zero that you are checking for, it's terminated by a `0x0D` (the enter).

A working version could be:

```
                bits       16
                org        0x7C00
start:          jmp        main

bgetkey:        pusha
                mov        ax, 0
                mov        ah, 10h
                int        16h
                mov        [.buf], ax
                popa
                mov        ax, [.buf]
                ret
                .buf       dw 0

prints:         pusha
.loop:
                mov        ah, 0x0e
                mov        al, [si]
                cmp        al, 0
                jz         print_end
                mov        bh, 0x00
                mov        bl, 0x07
                int        0x10
                inc        si
                jmp        .loop
print_end:      popa
                ret

main:           mov        ax, 0x0000           ; set register a
                mov        ds, ax               ;
                mov        bx, mem
                add        bx, word 2           ; point to after the pointer :)
                mov        word [mem], bx
                mov        si, welcome          ; set and prints
                call       prints               ;
type:           mov        si, qbuf             ; set prints ptr
                call       bgetkey              ; capture  input
                mov        [qbuf], al           ; set char to sz
                call       prints               ; call print str

                mov        bx, [mem]            ; put chr in mem
                cmp        bx, stop             ; compare loader
                je         oom                  ; end and memory
                mov        byte [bx], al
                add        bx, byte 1
                mov        [mem], bx            ;

                cmp        byte [qbuf], 0x0D    ; cmpr enter key
                jne        type                 ; continue  next
                mov        si, newline          ; print  newline
                call       prints               ;

                mov        bx, mem+2            ; start from after the pointer
printmem:       cmp        byte [bx], 0x0D      ; check for end
                je         halt                 ; halt  the  cpu
                mov        cl, [bx]
                mov        byte [qbuf], cl      ; buffer and cpy
                mov        si, qbuf             ; pointer to  si
                call       prints               ; print the char
                inc        bx
                jmp        printmem             ; jump beginning

oom:            mov        si, outomem          ; no more memory
                call       prints               ; print  message

halt:           mov        si, halting          ; cpu is halting
                call       prints               ; print last msg
                hlt                             ; halt  the  cpu

                welcome db "bootloader", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                newline db 0x0A, 0x00
                outomem db "out of memory", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                halting db "halting", 0x00
                qbuf       dw 0, 0
                mem        db 0

times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)db 0
                stop       dw 0xAA55
```

PS: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Why is the pusha/popa needed in the char reader? Don't software interrupts preserve all registers?  Doesn't mov ax, 1000h; int 16h; ret do the same thing?

Comment: @Gene it's not needed, but I haven't touched that part of the code. I didn't optimize it, just fixed the errors.

Comment: Yes, bochs does have a simple debugger built in.